# Find the minimum value in an array using its maximum value

Tags: java

Can you help whit this Question?

Given an int array of positive numbers, write a method `int findndMax(int[] array)` that returns
the maximum value. Then, write another method called `findMin` to find the minimum element
without comparing the array elements (use `findMax`)?

```
public int findMax(int[] array){ 
    int max = array[0]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        if (array[i] > max) 
            max = array[i]; 
    } 
    return max; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this? People won't do your homework here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Gah! Please don't post code in comments. Hard to read. If you have code to add, please add it to your question by editing your question.

Comment: And here's a clue: you're not allowed to compare elements in your list to get the minimum, but are you allowed to touch them? Like make an altered list by doing something to each individual element?

Comment: You can generate new arrays where you removed the max one. If you do this until nothing is left, the last element you have removed was the smallest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have wrote the method `findMax`, then multiply all array elements with **-1**, find the max and multiply the answer with **-1**.  But this is not efficient anyway, as you have to go through all array elements, possibly twice.

```
public int findMin(int[] array) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        array[i] *= -1;
    int min = -1 * findMax(array); 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        array[i] *= -1;
    return min; 
}
```

If you want to do it with one loop:

```
public int findMin(int[] array) { 
    int[] aux = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        aux[i] = -1 * array[i];
    int min = -1 * findMax(aux); 
    return min; 
}
```

Comment: nice idea
but i think you can not implement it without
two loops !!
it doesn't make sense !!
I can implement it with one loop !!

Comment: @Mr.Saad you can do it one loop to, but it doesn't improve the performance, number of calculations will be still same if you want the array to be unchanged. let me update with one loop.

Comment: thank you mister Anil for your help :)